# Modifying Interrupt Vector Table of Atmega32

Tags: avr, interrupts, avr-gcc

A project that I'm working on involves a cycle accurate interrupt service routine. This routine is written in AVR Assembly where I just wrote:

```
.org oc1aadr
rjmp INTRP
```

(to set up the IVT)
And it worked perfectly well. However I had to use both C and assembly for this project, so I switched to GCC and after looking up some documentation, found that I just have to write the routine with a label:

```
TIMER1_COMPA_vect:
```

Now the interrupt is working fine too, but the thing is that it now takes 3 cycles to enter into the ISR. On looking up the disassembler code, I saw that the IVT is like this:

```
+00000000:   940C002A    JMP     0x0000002A       Jump
+00000002:   940C0047    JMP     0x00000047       Jump
+00000004:   940C0047    JMP     0x00000047       Jump
+00000006:   940C0047    JMP     0x00000047       Jump
+00000008:   940C0047    JMP     0x00000047       Jump
+0000000A:   940C0047    JMP     0x00000047       Jump
+0000000C:   940C0047    JMP     0x00000047       Jump
+0000000E:   940C0049    JMP     0x00000049       Jump
+00000010:   940C0047    JMP     0x00000047       Jump
```

The JMP instruction takes 3 cycles unlike RJMP, which takes only 2. I've tried writing:

```
.org 0x0E
rjmp INTRP
```

But still it won't work, I've also tried writing (.section .init0) before .org, but still no effect. So, is there any way I can change the instruction to RJMP?
Note: Only the interrupt routine is written in assembly.

For my second question: Is there any difference in the clock cycles required by an instruction when using different compilers/assemblers?
MY entire routine takes 3 clock cycles less using GCC compared to AVR Assembler. I don't know whether GCC depends on AVR Assembler or not, but is there a possibility of this happening? (I'm asking this based on the AVR simulator output).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in [avr/interrupt.h line 228](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/interrupt_8h_source.html#l00228) which decides to use `jmp` on ATMEGA and `rjmp` on other micros. Presumably you could override it back to `rjmp` as long as you make sure your ISR's address is within the allowable range for `rjmp`.

The [documentation for avr/interrupt.h](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__interrupts.html) as mentioned in another answer explains how to mark the ISR as naked to avoid any function setup/teardown overhead. You could even write the function using inline assembly, but you can probably get exactly the instructions you want from C, too.

Comment: I tried that, but no effect. Anyways, I adjusted the 1 clock delay elsewhere, the problem no longer persists. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Interesting question "how does GCC generate the interrupt vector table"; I certainly learned something. You're right, the first part of my answer was wrong, that part of interrupt.h only defines a deprecated ISR aliasing mechanism.